# quadratic grid in which orthogonal triangle formed by grid points

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Determine all natural numbers $n$ with $n>1$ that applies:
If each grid point of a quadratic grid in the plane is colored with one of n given Colors, then there are always three grid points of the same color, that form a orthogonal triangle form whose catheters are parallel to the grid lines. It is a Cartesian coordinate system.

So I tried to find a solution to this question with Ramsey theory, but so far with no success.

Comment: @Maam no there are no other condition. I'm confused too :)

Comment: Apologies, I tried to delete immediately my comment but it was not done. I realized: if exactly one color satisfies (vertices of a right triangle), it is enough.